# Invert primary values in a photo

Tags: compositing-nodes, image

I am interested in trying to edit infrared photographs in Blender to match [this process](https://www.phographer.com/2014/11/processing-infrared-photos-raw-photoshop.html/3). In this process, the user uses Photoshop's Channel Mixer to swap the values of red, green and blue channels (other programs, such as Color Efex Pro, [seem to do it too](https://petapixel.com/2016/10/27/introduction-digital-infrared-photography/)).

I assume this would have to be done in the **Compositor**, but I haven't found a way to do it yet. I tried separating channels but it didn't work.

### Can one swap channels in Blender when editing photos or videos?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do pretty much whatever you want with the channels of an image with the compositing nodes. Look through the nodes in the Add menu(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> in the Compositor). In the Converter section there are a lot of interesting nodes and amongst them Separate RGBA and Combine RGBA nodes that split and combine channels, so you can simply connect the channels in any order you want. You can also use all kinds of maths and other manipulations:

[image]

Comment: Ah, great, I guess I wasn't too far off in my .blend file then!

Comment: Sorry, I only now checked your .blend file. I am a bit confused what is unclear to you then. You were doing pretty much the same. What are you struggling with then?

Comment: I'm not sure, I guess being able to copy the values in the first link of my question in an input field rather than just switching them? Or is that unimportant... I'm not sure

Comment: Thanks for helping, it didn't refresh the image so I didn't think my setup worked. I enabled background so I could see what it's doing. Thanks