# Nodes and vector colours of a 2D picture in Blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have a jpg picture as given below and I wanna have it entirely red with the red color having
the density which would follow the original picture. A .blend file using Nodes postcomposition would help.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selective color correction](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97335/selective-color-correction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your image into a separate RGB node and use only the red channel.  This is in the material editor, but there are similar compositor nodes.

[image]

Comment: Do you please have the 2 .blend files for your (good) suggestions ?

Comment: Read also: [Mask and convert color in photo/video](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191265/mask-and-convert-color-in-photo-video/191269#191269)

Comment: [how to chanbe a specific colour in an image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158999/how-to-change-a-specific-colour-in-an-image/159013#159013) and [invert primary colors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148570/invert-primary-values-in-a-photo/148573#148573)